# How to do http callback request in javascript without script tags but in js file?

Tags: javascript, http, twitter, request

i want to put this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/EricClaptonNews.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10"></script>
```

which works when i have it in my html file within script tags, 
inside one of my .js files?

Comment: because i need to edit the request dynamily which is why i can't do it in my index file but within my actual code!

Comment: The returned javascript object is already passed to the function defined in `callback`. You can do your editing there. I don't see the problem...

Comment: FYI: Twitter API 1 is soon to be deprecated - https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to make an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) to the above link, making sure to omit the `callback` parameter, as that is only required for `JSONP` requests.

However, as the Twitter domain is not in the same domain as your website, this call will fail the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

So your only option left (if you are unwilling to use `JSONP`) is to make the call from the server side.

Comment: You'll have to make the call from PHP using a function such as `file_get_contents();` or [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). This will return a JSON string which you can decode using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: ahh, sorry,  can't somebody please write me that little peace of code? i don't know php and i just need to do the request somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

head.innerHTML += "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/EricClaptonNews.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10"></script>";
```

or

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/EricClaptonNews.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10";

head.appendChild(script);
```

But I'm with @RobertHarvey why would you want to do this?

**EDIT:**

Reading your comment to @RobertHarvey you would want to go with the second method I suggested then you could build your url like this:

```
function url_builder(foo){
    var url = https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/EricClaptonNews.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count="+foo; //dynamically call a number stored in foo
    return url;
}

var url = url_builder(30);  //want to get 30 tweets instead of 10!
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;

head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in your html define tag `<form>`:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="Form1">
...

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then try this in your .js

```
document.forms[0].action="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/EricClaptonNews.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10";
document.forms[0].submit(true);
```

We hope it's helpful.